# best way to define multiple has-a relationship, where A has-a X, B has-a X, C has-a X

Tags: java, database, oop

I have a situation where A has-a X, B has-a X, C has-a X etc....
how can i ensure if A1 has-a X1, B1/C1/D1 cannot have X1. so on and so forth?

Is it ensured only through business logic?
I would like to know the best practice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you have some sort of junction table already which relates the possessors `A`, `B`, `C` to the items `X`, etc.  Something like this:

```
owner | item
A     | X
B     | Y
C     | Z
```

If you want to ensure that only one owner may own a given item, then all you need to do is to add a unique constraint on the `item` column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD UNIQUE (item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your questions, it appears that you have multiple tables (A, B, C, D, etc.) and then an X table.  Each of the main tables relate to the X table, but you want to ensure unique constraint against all table relationships to the X table.

If so, I'm not aware of a way without using business logic to accomplish that unless you could create another table that sits in between that houses the unique constraint and serves as the relationship table between all of the main tables and the X table if you want to avoid potentially complicated business logic coding.

TJ